# Filling a div with the current time

Tags: php, jquery, date

In the header of a page I want to insert a div that contains the current date. I am not sure if jquery can handle this (perhaps php) is a better way to go.

I want to populate the div in the header of the page with the current date in the format (example) 20th August 2013.

Comment: So you want to do this on the server (php) or on the client (jQuery)? Which one?

Comment: not sure what you want, jquery or PHP, or something else? We can't tell you what code to use. Also, it's pretty easy to find searching for "php date" http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use PHP's built-in `date()` function for this purpose:

```
<div id="foo"> 
<?php echo date('dS F Y'); ?>
</div>
```

Output:

```
23rd August 2013
```

Documentation: [**`date()`**](http://php.net/date)

Answer (score 0):

PHP (if short tags enabled in php.ini)

```
<div><?=date('jS F Y');?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the JS [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Example:

```
<div>
 <script>
 var d=new Date();
 document.write(d);
 </script>
</div>
```

results in:

```
Fri Aug 23 2013 20:10:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: If the info above would be incorrect, I'd have no problem witch your comment. Elas, why down my answer if it's correct? Because you feel like it? Strange rules around here.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. However, w3schools links are not welcome by most on SO because they teach bad programming habits and practices. I suggest removing the link from your answer. If you wish to include a link, use a more reputable source, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will be the easier, and more practical way to go.

jQuery doesn't have any built in libraries for formatting date/time. Therefore, it would require you to use an external jQuery plug-in, which would add more bloat to your site, or write several dozen lines of vanilla JavaScript to do what you can literally do in PHP with one line of code.

```
<div><?php echo date('jS F Y'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted: jQuery doesn't come with any useful date related functionality out-of-the-box but just for giggles, here's a suitable javascript alternative.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="myHeader">
  <div id="myDate"></div>
</div>

<script>
(function(){

    var d = new Date;
    var myDateFormat = d.getDate()
        + (['st','nd','rd'][(d.getDate()+'').substr(-1)-1] || 'th') + ' '
        + ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
            'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
        ][d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('myDate').innerHTML = myDateFormat;

})();
</script>
```

I felt compelled to play a bit of golf and squeeze it into a few lines to draw comparison with PHP.

---

Should also note that PHP will likely be printing the server's time unless you specify otherwise by declaring a time zone or applying an offset.  Like-wise, the javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object will be returning the time on the local machine - unless you specify otherwise by means of the UTC functions. i.e. who's time do you wish to display?

Comment: Yes the php solution is a lot simpler and easier to implement. Hopefully both solutions will help others in the future